# Problema com inserção de char especial via prompt

Tags: mysql

Caros, tenho uma tabela onde faço alguns inserts com dados contendo char especial. Atualmente uso o Toad for Mysql, e quando faço a inserção por esse editor, tudo ocorre de maneira correta, os chars especiais sobem normalmente, porém, se uso o source @script.sql do mysql command line para subir os mesmos dados, estes não sobem os chars especiais, e sim, um outro char. Gostaria de saber como faço para subir pelo prompt da mesma maneira que subo pelo Toad.

Table:

```
DROP TABLE

IF EXISTS DOBER.FINANCEIRO_TRANSPORTADORA;
CREATE TABLE DOBER.FINANCEIRO_TRANSPORTADORA (
    TRANSPK INT (3) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
    ,CODIGO INT (3) NOT NULL
    ,NATUREZA VARCHAR(16)
    ,NOME VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
    ,DATA_MODIF DATETIME
    ,USUARIO VARCHAR(10)
    ,PRIMARY KEY (TRANSPK)
    ) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET UTF8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

INSERT:

```
INSERT INTO DOBER.FINANCEIRO_TRANSPORTADORA(
CODIGO,
NATUREZA,
NOME,
DATA_MODIF,
USUARIO) VALUES
(1,'Pessoa Jurídica','TRANSPORTADORA1',NOW(),'Usuario1'),
(2,'Pessoa Jurídica','TRANSPORTADORA2',NOW(),'Usuario2')

    Resultado com o Toad:
1  |  Pessoa Jurídica  |  TRANSPORTADORA1  |  30/10/2014 13:46:51  |  Usuario1
2  |  Pessoa Jurídica  |  TRANSPORTADORA2  |  30/10/2014 13:46:51  |  Usuario2

Resultado com MySqlCommand:
1  |  Pessoa Jur├¡dica  |  TRANSPORTADORA1  |  30/10/2014 13:46:51  |  Usuario1
2  |  Pessoa Jur├¡dica  |  TRANSPORTADORA2  |  30/10/2014 13:46:51  |  Usuario2
```

Comment: Uso o notepad++ e o arquivo esta com codificação UTF-8

Comment: A codificação padrão do MySql pode estar interferindo (caso não seja UTF-8). Experimento passar o parâmetro `--default-character-set=utf8`. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_default-character-set

Comment: Tente trocar aspas simples por duplas.

Comment: Caffé, este ultimo comentário foi a solução, inseri o --default-character-set=utf8 no momento da conexão e tudo foi inserido corretamente.

Comment: Legal. Eu estava atualizando minha resposta. De qualquer modo se o arquivo não estiver em UTF-8 você também terá problema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A codificação de caracters da sua tabela é **UTF-8**.

O seu editor *Toad for Mysql* deve estar usando esta mesma codificação e por isso o `INSERT` funciona como esperado.

Procure salvar o arquivo texto que contém o `INSERT` (este usado via linha de comando) também com a codificação `UTF-8`. Isto deve resolver o problema.

Usando o editor de textos *Notepad++* você é capaz de selecionar esta codificação.

Além disso, pode ser necessário informar a codificação em que o arquivo deve ser interpretado (caso o padrão do MySql ou o client do MySql não estejam configurados para UTF-8). Neste caso, passe o parâmetro:

`--default-character-set=utf8`

Veja: [4.5.1.1 mysql Options](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_default-character-set).

Comment: Obrigado!!!!!!!!!!!!!